# Find out the internet connection of a user

Tags: javascript, php, performance, internet-connection

I want to know what internet connection does a user has.This information will then be used in my php script. Logic will be as follows

```
if $connection <= 1mbps then 
//do something 
elseif $connection >=2mbps then 
//do another thing
fi
```

Hope you get the idea and can help me out to find a way to determine a user internet connection accurately

Thanks to you all

Comment: You could trigger a download of some bigger file via an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest()` call (aka AJAX) and take the time it takes until it is complete (`readyState == 4`). To get some accurate measurement, that file has to be big though and I'm not sure your users would be happy downloading some useless stuff.

Comment: @z80crew i think the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This might not be completely what you're looking for (read the bold part), but I doubt if anything else is possible.

This script sends 512 KB of HTML comments to your client. Parsing that HTML may add to the total transfer time, **so don't take this as your raw download speed.**

Quoted from: PHP Speed test

Source is here:

http://jan.moesen.nu/code/php/speedtest/index.php?source=1

Hope that helps.

Comment: Youtube achieve this pretty accurately...the default video quality changes depending on your connection.I am not looking for a php only method.